# Decompress tarred file system into mounted partition

Tags: backup, tar

let's say that I backed up the file system on an installed distro into the file backup.tar.gz.
I have the file backup.tar.gz in my home dir and want to decompress it directly into the partition sda1 mounted on /mnt/sda1, in a way that I get the directories in the / of the sda1 partition (not /mnt/sda1/backup but rather /bin boot root sbin etc... to be clear).
Is there a way to do that in a single command?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no `/` or `/bin` directory in `/mnt/sda1`. `/mnt/sda1` is just the directory where the filesystem of `/dev/sda1` is mounted. As far as the operating system is concerned, the directory `/` is the system root of where everything is mounted including `/mnt/sda1`.

Comment: You should examine the first few lines of the report shown by `tar tvzf backup.tar.gz`. Gnu/tar should have removed any leading `/` from the names to make them relative (so they can be restored without blowing away existing /bin, /usr etc.) You just need to `cd` into a directory in `/mnt/sda1` named such that the `cd` and the relative name "join up" sensibly.

Comment: What I meant by / in sda1 is that I want to reproduce the root of the original system I backed up into the sda1 partition. If I tar tvzf backup.tar.gz to /mnt(sda1 what i get is a dir named backup containin ght filesystem whereas I want the file system itself in sda1.

Comment: If that's what you are trying to do then just `cd /mnt/sda1` and deompress the archive there. There won't be a `/` but the root of `/mnt/sda1` and the rest will the there. For example, there will be `/mnt/sda1/usr` and `/mnt/sda1/var` . I haven't personally tried this but you may need to create the symlink of `/mnt/sda1/bin` > `/mnt/sda1/usr/bin` and `/mnt/sda1/lib64` > `/mnt/sda1/usr/lib64`, etc.

Comment: If i copy the package backup.tar.gz to /mnt/sda1 and decompress it there, what I get is /mnt/sda1/backup/bin.... which is not what i need. I know of alternatives ways to do this, but my question is if there is a way to do this in a single commnd.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found this solution.

```
tar xzvf backup.tar.gz --strip=1 -C /path/to/target/dir
```

Did the trick.